# Sqlite - while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) is not executing

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am trying to get the highest value in the Points column in my DB, however the sqlite_step statement never get executed.
This is the method with this in it.

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getMax {
[self databaseInit];
highScore *newMax = [[highScore alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *maxPointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath,&peopleDB)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *selectMaxSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT MAX POINTS FROM PEOPLE"];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(peopleDB, [selectMaxSQL UTF8String],-1,&statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
            newMax.max = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

        }
        [maxPointsArray addObject:newMax];
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(peopleDB);
return maxPointsArray;
}
```

If it makes a difference the databaseInit method is -

```
+(void)databaseInit {
//get documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths [0];
//create path to database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"people.db"]];
dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
}
```

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated, let me know if any more code is needed.

Comment: put the breakpoint, and check what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not executed because your query is wrong.

Assuming that `points` is a field of your `people` table, the query should be:

```
SELECT MAX(points) FROM people
```

Comment: Feel like such an idiot, the one thing i didnt think of was that my query was wrong. Thanks so much !!

Comment: Can happen no worry ;)

Comment: Its because i ran the query through SQlite DB Browser and it returned the value it was ment to

Answer (score 0):

You have the immediate answer, but the long term solution is to log `sqlite3_errmsg` if any SQLite functions fail. The way your code is written, you have no way of knowing which of the calls failed and why.

Thus, you may want:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getMax {
    int rc;

    [self databaseInit];
    highScore *newMax = [[highScore alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *maxPointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if ((rc = sqlite3_open(dbpath, &peopleDB)) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *selectMaxSQL = "SELECT MAX(POINTS) FROM PEOPLE";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(peopleDB, selectMaxSQL, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            if ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW){
                newMax.max = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                [maxPointsArray addObject:newMax];
            } else {
                if (rc == SQLITE_DONE) {
                    NSLog(@"No record returned");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Step failed %s (%d)", sqlite3_errmsg(peopleDB), rc);
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Prepare failed %s (%d)", sqlite3_errmsg(peopleDB), rc);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Open failed %d", rc);
    }
    sqlite3_close(peopleDB);
    return maxPointsArray;
}
```

If you had done this with your original SQL, it would have reported precisely where in the SQL it encountered the error. Furthermore, if you have any problems in the future, this sort of defensive programming will help diagnose problems more quickly.

It's also worth noting that it's generally recommended not to open and close the database with every database call, but rather to open the database only once. It's more efficient and people have reported problems when constantly opening and closing databases.

Comment: BTW, a minor point unrelated to your immediate issue, but I presume that these class methods are accessing global variables. Stylistically, it's probably better to make these local variables where possible, instance variables where not, and if you employ instance variables, then make the methods instance methods rather than class methods. You might even want to make some of these variables local variables (e.g. sqlite3_stmt) where appropriate. It's completely unrelated to your immediate issue, but it may make your code maintenance easier in the future.